# Java ObjectInputStream refill: StreamCorruptedException in stead of EOFException

Tags: java, objectinputstream, eofexception

I was wondering, why does `refill()` throw a `StreamCorrruptedException` when it finds an unexpected EOF in the middle of a data block? (`ObjectInputStream.java:2538`)

Wouldn't it be better if it throws an `EOFException` or is there a different reason to throw a `StreamCorrruptedException` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is distinction between reaching the end of a *well-formed* stream and reaching the end of stream *mid-object*.  if i'm reading a stream with an unknown number of objects, i can just keep calling `readObject()` until getting EOFException, and i know i have read everything successfully.  if i got the same exception if `readObject()` was part way through reading an object, i wouldn't know that the last object was corrupted.

Comment: Thanks, I thought something along those lines, but then I thought that it could also be possible that the wrong kind of object was read. This would be a bug, but then the stream isn't really corrupt.